# How to get all timezones list in Qt?

Tags: qt, timezone, qt4.7

Is there any way to get lists of all timezones IST, ET etc.

I have to use them in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to somehow find it during runtime, or for your source code? If the second case, you can use [this list](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/).

Comment: I need it for my source code, but if a user select timezone, my app should show time in that standard. how can I do that ?

Comment: To achieve this, probably either solution is possible. Hardcoding the timezones in your source code might be a simpler approach, but getting them from the system has the advantage of not needing maintenance, assuming that in the rare case that timezones get changed, they will be reflected in the external resource you are using. It might seem like an overkill, though, seeing how this should be an extremely rare event.

Answer (score 5):

The [ICU Library](http://site.icu-project.org/) is portable and can be used in a Qt application. (It has a C/C++ API.) Among its many other features, is has a `TimeZone` class that can enumerate the time zones known by the system.

- [TimeZone Class](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classTimeZone.html)

It might be overkill if all you need is a simple list, but if you expect to use these time zones and interact with other metadata (locales, etc.), this would be a good solution.

Comment: I dont know from where to get libraries from the given link, Is there any way to directly Add these libraries in my symbain project?

Comment: The download page is: http://site.icu-project.org/download. That page contains links to binary and source downloads, as well as the address of the Subversion repository. I have no experience with the Symbian environment, so I'm afraid I can't offer any specifics; the ICU library is a normal C/C++ library--include the headers, add the path to the libraries to your linker. You might want to create a new question for Symbian-specific help.

Answer (score 3):

There is a another example using the new QTimeZone class in qt5.2 described [here](http://www.ics.com/blog/whats-new-qt-52-qtimezone).

They create a custom Widget which lists all known timezones plus their special settings like daylight saving times and such.

The basic code posted there is:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QList>
#include <QTimeZone>

#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Fill in combo box.
    QList<QByteArray> ids = QTimeZone::availableTimeZoneIds();
    foreach (QByteArray id, ids) {
        ui->timeZoneComboBox->addItem(id);
    }

    // Connect combo box to slot to update fields.
    connect(ui->timeZoneComboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),
            SLOT(UpdateFields()));

    // Update fields for initial value.
    UpdateFields();
}

void Widget::UpdateFields() {

  QByteArray id = ui->timeZoneComboBox->currentText().toLatin1();
  QTimeZone zone = QTimeZone(id);

  // Fill in fields for current time zone.
  if (zone.isValid()) {
      ui->descriptionLabel->setText(tr("<b>Description:</b> ") + id);
      ui->countryLabel->setText(tr("<b>Country:</b> ") +    
          QLocale::countryToString(zone.country()));
      ui->hasDaylightTimeCheckBox->setChecked(zone.hasDaylightTime());
      ui->isDaylightTimeCheckBox->setChecked(
          zone.isDaylightTime(QDateTime::currentDateTime()));
      ui->hasTransitionsCheckBox->setChecked(zone.hasTransitions());
      QDateTime zoneTime = QDateTime(
          QDate::currentDate(), QTime::currentTime(), zone).toLocalTime();
      ui->dateEdit->setDate(zoneTime.date());
      ui->timeEdit->setTime(zoneTime.time());

      QTimeZone::OffsetData offset = zone.nextTransition(
          QDateTime::currentDateTime());
      if (offset.atUtc != QDateTime()) {
          ui->nextTransitionLabel->setEnabled(true);
          ui->nextTransitionLabel->setText(
          tr("<b>Next transition:</b> %1").arg(offset.atUtc.toString()));
      } else {
          ui->nextTransitionLabel->setEnabled(false);
          ui->nextTransitionLabel->setText(
              tr("<b>Next transition:</b> none"));
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes try this example

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_get_list_of_Time_Zones_in_Qt_Maemo_application

Comment: Note this is not a Qt native solution, so it's not portable to all platforms.

Comment: Moi, i know that :), but should give "abhishek" the right way to approach